How can i implement incremental authorization with google oauth. Not much content on this, tried next auth, supabase, clerk but can't get it done
What i want to achieve is, after signing in with google I have the default scope but I want some extra scope after signing in so how can i do it programmatically. So that's what i want to achieve. Tried Next auth/authjs, supabase and clerk but can't figure out a way to do this. If anyone have any idea please let me know. Any blogs or repos where it is done will be great
Tried Next auth, supabase and Clerk but can't get it done. Google sdk has support for it but have to handle the whole pipeline by myself and it will take so much time which i don't have right now.
